# Java static object scope in singleton design pattern not throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have created a class as below while practicing singleton pattern:

```
class Singleton
{
    // static variable single_instance of type Singleton
    private static final Singleton single_instance = new Singleton();

    // private constructor restricted to this class itself
    private Singleton()
    {
        System.out.println("Yahoo");
    }

    // static method to create instance of Singleton class
    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        return single_instance;
    }
    public static void getDemo()
    {
        System.out.println("YOHOO");
    }
}
```

I know its not entirely correct. But then in the main class, in the main function I called this way:

```
package common;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton tmp = Singleton.getInstance();
        tmp = null;
        System.out.println(tmp);
        tmp.getDemo();

    }

}
```

And what prints is this :

```
Yahoo
null
YOHOO
```

But why not a **null pointer exception** when calling getDemo() the second time?
I am not sure if I am missing any scope details but would appreciate the help.

Comment: Your method is static that's why it doesn't care where it points. It's a regular CLASS method call.

Comment: In essence, the target reference (`tmp`) will not be evaluated, as it is defined in [JLS §15.12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a static method by prefixing it by the class or a variable declared with the type of the class will produce the same result.
The compiler will not evaluate the `tmp` object to invoke the method but will invoke directly the static method.

As stated by the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1) :

> **15.12.4.1. Compute Target Reference (If Necessary)**
>
> There are six cases to consider, depending on the form of the method
>   invocation:
>
> - If the form is MethodName - that is, just an Identifier - then:
>
>   - If the invocation mode is static, then there is no target reference.

Note that the compiler should also emit the following warning :

> The static method getDemo() from the type Singleton should be accessed
>   in a static way

So you should follow this advise and replace it by :

```
Singleton.getDemo();
```

The disassembled version of the `main()` method of the compiled class shows that :

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #16                 // Method common/Singleton.getInstance:()Lcommon/Singleton;
       3: astore_1
       4: aconst_null
       5: astore_1
       6: getstatic     #22                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       9: aload_1
      10: invokevirtual #28                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      13: invokestatic  #34                 // Method Lcommon/Singleton.getDemo:()V
      16: return
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the disassembled version, as I got confused when I saw  10:    invokevirtual #28             13: invokestatic  #34

Comment: The disassembled version shows detail internals. Here `#...` are indexes written during the compilation and used to reference invoked methods. The thing that should interest you is :      `invokestatic ...  // Method Lcommon/Singleton.getDemo:()V` that explains why your code don't throw a NPE at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling is a static method. It does not depend upon the pointer value. It just see the reference type to call the method.